# Preloading images before Lightslider runs

Tags: jquery, preload

I'm trying to force Lightslider (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html) to run only after all its images and contents are loaded. How can this be done?
I have achieved the goal with the code below, but on Chrome it always fires an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined

This error does not prevent the behaviour from being correct, but we cannot have the errors firing due to mandatory standards.

Do you have any clues on how to solve this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightslider.css"/>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="Js/lightslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
        gallery: true,
        item: 1,
        thumbItem: 6,
        slideMargin: 0,
        thumbMargin: 5,
        animateThumb: true,
        cssEasing: 'ease',
        easing: 'linear',
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        auto: true,
        loop: true,
        onSliderLoad: function () {
            $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');                        
        }
    });
    $('#image-gallery').autoplaySlider.pause();
});
$(window).load(function () {
     $('#image-gallery').autoplaySlider.play();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your lightSlider creation into

```
$(window).load(function () {

   $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
       gallery: true,
       item: 1,
       ...

});
```

And don't call pause() and play().

As a general rule, if you are going to work with images and expect them to be loaded then it is better to code inside $(window).load

I hope it works!